# MATLAB Print Cell Array

Tags: cell-array

I am trying to print a 3x3 cell array of strings and I need to do it with fprintf(). So far I have the following, but it doesn't print out a 3x3:

```
for index=1:length(cell) 
        fprintf('%s\n',cell{index}); 
    end
```

Comment: show us your output which you are getting.

Comment: I just get 2 values like this: 
val1
val2

Comment: Now I tried this: for index=1:length(punnett) 
            fprintf('%s %s\n',punnett{index,:},punnett{:,index}); 
        end

Comment: How would you print out a 3x3 array? I think that would be the same as printing out a 3x3 cell array